# Set dropdown menu button width to block in VuetifyJS component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using the [VuetifyJS dropdown menu component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus) and I need to get it to the same width of the other button in my attached example. Unfortunately the *block* settings don't work.

CodePen example of the issue: `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/djvyVw?&editors=101`

```
 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-flex xs10 offset-xs1>

        <v-btn block round depressed dark large color="green darken-4">
          <v-icon large>info</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-menu offset-y>
          <v-btn block outline round depressed dark large color="yellow darken-3" slot="activator">
            <v-icon>info</v-icon>Learn More</v-btn>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-tile v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" @click="" :class="item.color">
              <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile>
          </v-list>
        </v-menu>

      </v-flex>
    </v-card>

  </v-app>
</div>
```

How to get it to full width like the other button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply give `v-menu` the `full-width` attribute:

```
<v-menu offset-y full-width>
   ...
</v-menu>
```

Comment: Strange, I tried it yesterday but it didn't work. Now it does, thank you

Comment: I use Vuetify v1.5+ and the full-width doesn't work; and this is a common error, am yet to get a solution by Vuetify except individual hacks/tweaks